# Автоматический клик на кнопку javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

У меня в коде присутствует выпадающий список в середине страницы, я хочу, чтобы он открывался при загрузке страницы. Для этого прописан js код снизу(тут он не работает почему-то), но при загрузке страницы окно пролистывается до самой кнопки. Хотелось бы чтобы кнопка нажималась при загрузке страницы и сама страница не пролистывалась.

```js
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){
              'use strict';
              var el = document.querySelector('.button-first');
              setTimeout(function(){
                el.click();
              }, 0);
            });
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div><button class="button-first">кнопка</button></div>
```

Comment: А зачем нажимать кнопку, нельзя onload выполнить функцию, которая привязана к кнопке?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: "Хотелось бы чтобы кнопка нажималась при загрузке страницы" что происходит по нажатию кнопки? Вызывается какая-то функция? Можно не нажимать программно кнопку, а сразу вызвать функцию после загрузки страницы.